# mulesoft dataweave 2.0 mapObject recursion match JSON values

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a kafka message listener connector and after that there is the connector 'Avro Scheme' by mulesoft. Now this Avro Scheme connector replaces parts of my JSON where there is a validation error. I'm trying to see where & what exception occured.

I have following payload:

```html
[
  {
    "movementId": "a4fa404e-6983-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
    "movementNumber": "123456789",
    "movementDate": "2022-11-22",
    "originLocationId": {
      "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et",
      "kind": "AvroReadingException",
      "cause": null,
      "message": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et",
      "stackTrace": [
        
      ],
      "suppressed": [
        
      ]
    },
    "originLocationCode": "jos",
    "actDepartureDateTime": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
    "estArrivalDateTime": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
    "delays": null,
    "event": {
      "id": {
        "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur",
        "kind": "AvroReadingException",
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur",
        "stackTrace": [
          
        ],
        "suppressed": [
          
        ]
      },
      "created": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
      "source": {
        "application": "TEST",
        "server": "aute reprehenderit et",
        "instance": "exercitation"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now I need to fetch the paths of all the JSON objects where the value 'AvroReadingException' occurs. It doesn't really matter if it is the full path to the JSON key, but something to identify where the exception was thrown.

In given example the expected result could be:

```html
[
    {
        "originLocationId": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et"
    },
    {
        "event.id": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur"
    }
[
```

I started with following test, but cannot seem to get it to work:

```html
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun test(root, value, opt) = do {
    value match {
        case arr is Array -> value map (value, index) -> test(null, value, null)
        case obj is Object -> value mapObject { ($$): test($$, $, root) }
        else -> 
            if (value is String and (value contains 'AvroReadingException'))
                value ++ "------" ++ opt
            else
                "++++"
    }
}
---
test(null, payload, null)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify one more thing. I see you have handled arrays in your dataweave too. If that is the case can you also add what should be the expected output if there is `AvroReadingException` exception one of the elements but array has multiple elements? Do you need index of the element in that case?

Comment: `the full path of all the JSON objects where the value 'AvroReadingException' occurs.` but you only show the value of the `message` key in the output. Please clarify how you construct the expect output.

Comment: @HarshankBansal: i have added isArray in my recursion to just loop arrays as well. I did a test and the value in array is replaced with an object.

I have edited the title and also what my wanted result is, it doesn't really matter if it is the full path. I just need something to identify where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Okay, so you do not need this exact output. I am adding an answer. It is not the exact output as you mentioned. but I think this one makes more sense.

Comment: Suggestion for title: "How to get path for certain fields based on their value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following. I have broken the logic in multiple functions to make it more readable.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

// This is just a small utility function to easily concatenate strings to get path
fun appendToPath(currentPath, pathToAppend) = 
    if(isEmpty(currentPath)) pathToAppend
    else currentPath ++ "." ++ pathToAppend

fun isRequiredExceptionObject(data) = 
    (data is Object) and (data.kind == "AvroReadingException")

/**
 * This is the recursive function. The path is basically the path
 * that has been collected till now. For example. In your case
 * for calculating "event.id", when the function is called recursively this value will be "event"
 */
fun getAvroReadingExceptions(validationPayload: Object, path="") = 
    entriesOf(validationPayload)
    reduce ((item, accumulator = {}) -> 
        item.value match {
            
            case value if(isRequiredExceptionObject(value)) -> {
                    (accumulator),
                    (path appendToPath item.key): value.message
            }
            case is Object -> {
                (accumulator),
                (getAvroReadingExceptions(item.value, path appendToPath item.key))
            }
            case is Array -> {
                (accumulator),
                (item.value map getAvroReadingExceptions($, path appendToPath item.key ++ "[$($$)]"))
            }

            else -> accumulator
        }
    )
---
payload map getAvroReadingExceptions($)
```

This also handles internal arrays. I have used the following input and added an array `arrayTest` which has 3 elements, among which 2 has a field that is `AvroReadingException`.

```json
[
  {
    "movementId": "a4fa404e-6983-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
    "movementNumber": "123456789",
    "movementDate": "2022-11-22",
    "originLocationId": {
      "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et",
      "kind": "AvroReadingException",
      "cause": null,
      "message": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et",
      "stackTrace": [
        
      ],
      "suppressed": [
        
      ]
    },
    "originLocationCode": "jos",
    "actDepartureDateTime": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
    "estArrivalDateTime": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
    "delays": null,
    "event": {
      "id": {
        "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur",
        "kind": "AvroReadingException",
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur",
        "stackTrace": [
          
        ],
        "suppressed": [
          
        ]
      },
      "created": "2022-11-21T11:08:17.057",
      "source": {
        "application": "TEST",
        "server": "aute reprehenderit et",
        "instance": "exercitation"
      }
    },
    "arrayTest": [
      {
        "field1": "sdf",
        "field2": {
          "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string in array: element3",
          "kind": "AvroReadingException",
          "cause": null,
          "message": "Invalid UUID string in array: element1",
          "stackTrace": [
            
          ],
          "suppressed": [
            
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "field1": "sdf",
        "field2": "sdf"
      },
      {
        "field1": "sdf",
        "field2": {
          "localizedMessage": "Invalid UUID string in array: element3",
          "kind": "AvroReadingException",
          "cause": null,
          "message": "Invalid UUID string in array: element3",
          "stackTrace": [
            
          ],
          "suppressed": [
            
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the output from the Dataweave

```js
[
  {
    "originLocationId": "Invalid UUID string: ipsum et",
    "event.id": "Invalid UUID string: Excepteur",
    "arrayTest[0].field2": "Invalid UUID string in array: element1",
    "arrayTest[2].field2": "Invalid UUID string in array: element3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks! I'm accepting this as an answer.

Comment: I just realized I used `flatMap` instead of `map`. This does not need `flatMap` so I have updated it